# plzz password_verify not working

Tags: php, mysql

Unfortunately I did not find the solution to the problem that I am a beginner, and I do not know why this function does not work and how I will use it.If someone gives me the solution written to understand the code and the problem plzz. (PS: dsl for just google translation)

```
(//Really 20 hours i try. No solution...(page login)      if (isset($_POST['connexion']))
{ $pseudoconnect=htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudoconnect']);
$passwordconnect=htmlspecialchars($_POST['passwordconnect']);
if (!empty('$pseudoconnect') AND !empty('$passwordconnect'))
{
$pseudoconnectlenght=strlen($pseudoconnect) ;
$passwordconnectlenght=strlen($passwordconnect) ;
if ($pseudoconnectlenght<3 || $pseudoconnectlenght>10 || $passwordconnectlenght<3 || $passwordconnectlenght >10)
{               
echo "remplis tous les infos exacte";
}
else
{                       
$repnom = $connect->prepare("SELECT password FROM membres WHERE pseudo=? ");
$repnom->execute(array($passwordconnect));
$userinfo= $repnom->fetch();
$_SESSION['password']= $userinfo['password'];
if (password_verify($_POST['passwordconnect'], $userinfo['password']))
{
echo "valid";
} else {
echo "pas valid";}}}
```

(page registration work correct )I use password_hash and its function well..PS: dsl for just google translation)

```
if (isset($_POST['envoyer'])) 
        {


            if (!empty($_POST['pseudo']) AND !empty($_POST['password'])) 
            {
                    $pseudo=htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudo']);
                    $password=htmlspecialchars($_POST['password']);
                    //$password=password_hash('password',PASSWORD_DEFAULT,['cost'=>12]);

                      $pseudolenght=strlen($pseudo);
                      $passwordlenght=strlen($password);
                      /*verifier les champs */
                        if ($pseudolenght<4 ||$pseudolenght>10 || $passwordlenght<4 || $passwordlenght> 10 ) 
                          { 

                                            echo "pass ou pseudo pas correct";
                           }    
                                else //enregistrement et verifier pseudo
                                    {

                                        $repetepseudo = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM membres WHERE pseudo=?");
                                        $repetepseudo->execute(array($pseudo));
                                        $existpseudo = $repetepseudo->rowCount();
                                        //verifier pseudo si déja existe
                                                if ($existpseudo == 0 )
                                                    {
                                                        //hasher password

                                                        $hash=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT,['cost'=>12]);

                                                        $sql = "INSERT INTO membres (pseudo,password) VALUES (?,?)";
                                                        $query = $connect->prepare($sql);
                                                        $query->execute(array($pseudo,$hash));





                                                            echo "enregistrement valide";
                                                            //header('location: html.php');

                                                     }

                                                        else
                                                            {
                                                                echo "déja utiliser";
                                                    }
                                                    }


                                                            }  //if empty
                                                                    else {

                                                                                echo "remplir tous les champs ";
                                                                          }





                                                                                                }//if isset eenvoyer
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a test file and database and tested your exact PHP code, and it worked.

EXCEPT I HAD TO CHANGE ONE THING. In your SQL statement "SELECT password FROM membres WHERE pseudo=? " you are selecting WHERE 'pseudo', but when you execute the query, notice that you are using array($passwordconnect) in the execute(). Don't you mean to use array($pseudoconnect)? Surely you are looking for a username but currently you are searching with the password ($passwordconnect) instead of ($pseudoconnect).

If that does not fix the issue, I can conclude that EITHER:

1.) Either or both of your $_POSTs are not arriving to your server. Empty the PHP file (be sure to be back it up!) and var_dump() the first two $_POST lines like this:

```
$pseudoconnect=htmlspecialchars($_POST['pseudoconnect']);
$passwordconnect=htmlspecialchars($_POST['passwordconnect']);
var_dump($pseudoconnect);
var_dump($passwordconnect);
```

If the username and password are not what they are supposed to be, then the issue is that you are not $_POST-ing correctly to the PHP file.

or 2.) Your SQL query is incorrect. Maybe you are misspelling something or making some little error in your statement. Again, use var_dump(), this tool will be very useful to you in your PHP lifetime. var_dump($userinfo) like so:

```
$userinfo= $repnom->fetch();
var_dump($userinfo);
```

If nothing is shown, double check every little thing in your SQL query.

Comment: thank you for you answer , 1-The first 1-) element you give me (ex if I enter pseudoconnect (jone) passwordconnect (jone) displays (jone jone not valid)..2-the problem I did not understand, the second  2-) display string(4) "jone" string(5) "jone " bool(false) pas valid ....Is it a problem on sql??

Comment: Try changing this line `$repnom->execute(array($passwordconnect));` to `$repnom->execute(array($pseudoconnect));`